# Re-order fields with jQuery

Tags: jquery, append

Forgive me if the title is not correct, but I can't explain myself very well..

I have a dynamic form, the user can add extra fields with jquery. (append)
There's an id for every field: 1,2,3,4.. For every field there's a button, with same id number.
The user can remove fields from the DOM with a click. With the remove function I also remove the associated buttons.

```
<div class="fields">
    <input type="text" id="field-id-1">
    <input type="text" id="field-id-2">
    <input type="text" id="field-id-2">
</div>

<div class="buttons">
    <input type="submit" id="button-id-1">
    <input type="submit" id="button-id-2">
    <input type="submit" id="button-id-3">
</div>
```

After every remove action, I would like to re-order the buttons, and the fields, so for example I have  fields-buttons, with the following ids: #1, #2, #3. If the user removes the #1, I would like to change #2 -> #1, and #3 -> #2.

The question is looks simple, but I'm a little bit confused. I hope you understood my problem.

Comment: Can you explain the point in changing the IDs.

Comment: @j08691: really funny, I didn't forget to post the code, because I'm looking for an idea, because I don't have.. don't know how to start, which function to use.

Comment: @Popnoodles: The users can add maximum 20 extra fields, this is the maximum, but if they remove for example 3 fields, the latest id will be 23. I display the number of the fields above the inputs, and it looks very ugly when ID 10 followed by ID 13. That's the reason.

Comment: I assume this page will not be submitted as changing the id's they relate to would not make much sense. So I gather you actually want to renumber the question id's (not really reorder as the *order* is still the same)

Comment: @user1452062 it looks ugly? To who - Mr jQuery? There is nothing in the code that shows those numbers are visible to the user. It seems that what you want to do serves no real purpose.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: yes you are true, I would like to re-number the ids.

Comment: Q: What do you click to remove the items?

Comment: @Popnoodles: Yes, I forgot to add the labels, but the question is still same. How to re-number the id's.

Comment: Labels? So you're displaying numbers? Use `<ol>` and let the browser do that for you. Zero unnecessary javascript required.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: I didn't add that part, but here is the code:

`$(document).on('click', '.remove', (function(){
  var rmId = $(this).attr('href').slice(4);
  $('.l-id-'+rmId).remove();
  $('.tag-id-'+rmId).remove();
 }));`

Comment: @Popnoodles: it's a really good idea, but how is it possible with jquery?

Comment: It needs no jQuery to use an `<ol>`!

Comment: For the test below I just made clicking on an input delete it and the matching submit. Use F12 debug tools in Chrome to inspect the new element ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not debating the usefulness of the question, but to answer it as it is written (including the comments):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/srB63/2/

```
// Test: For now click on the input to delete it
$(document).on('click','[id^=field-id]', function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.remove();
    // Remove the matching button
    $('[id^=button-id]').eq($this.index()).remove();
    // Renumber the remaining inputs sequentially
    $('[id^=field-id]').each(function(idx){
        $(this).attr('id', 'field-id-' + ++idx);
    });
    // Renumber the remaining buttons sequentially
    $('[id^=button-id]').each(function(idx){
        $(this).attr('id', 'button-id-' + ++idx);
    });
});
```

`[id^=` matches the start of an attribute string value